# Using the fundamental isomorphism theorem to show that $D_{24} / \{ e, a^4, a^8\} \cong D_8$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=D_{24}$, let $N=\lbrace e, a^4, a^8\rbrace\subset G$ and let $H=D_8$. Use the fundamental isomorphism theorem to show that $G / N \cong D_8$.

I can't see how I can show this without knowing the relevant isomorphism for $D_{24}\rightarrow D_8$.

Comment: Map rotation by $\alpha$ to rotation by $3\alpha$

Comment: There is no isomorphism $D_{24} \to D_8$. You need to find a surjective homomorphism $D_{24} \to D_8$.

Comment: Thanks Hagen, I've defined a homomorphism $\psi(ba^n)=dc^{n mod 4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you represent $D_{24}=\{e,a,a^2, \dots , a^{10},a^{11}, b, ba, ba^2, \cdots ba^{10},ba^{11}\}$, with $a^{12}=e=b^2$ and $bab=a^{-1}$, and similarly $D_{8}=\{e,x,x^2,x^3,y, yx, yx^2, yx^3\}$ with $x^4=e=y^2$ and $yxy=x^{-1}$, then try to prove that the map $\phi :D_{24} \rightarrow D_8$, defined by $\phi(a)=x$ and $\phi(b)=y$ is a well-defined surjective homomorphism, with $N=ker(\phi)=\{e,a^4,a^8\}$. The fundamental isomorphism (or first isomorphism) theorem then tells you that $D_{24}/N \cong D_8$.